# How do I solve the below system of congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, congruences

I'm new here , i want to solve the below system which $(x, y)$ are a paire in $\mathbb{N²}$.

$2x+2y= 1\bmod 10,4x+y= 7\bmod 10$

Thank you for your help

Comment: Well then, $4x + 4y \equiv 2$ and $4x + y \equiv 7$ gives $3y \equiv 5 \mod(10)$. What does that tell you about $y$?

Comment: I think y=5 mod (10)

Comment: That's correct. So then we get $2x \equiv 1 \mod(10)$; does that have a solution?

Comment: no solution exist since 10 = 0 mod 2

Comment: If you mean that $2x$ must be even while $10m + 1$ must be odd, then yes, that's a perfectly good answer. Congratulations, you solved your own problem!

Comment: yes ,thank you for your help

Comment: Hint: consider it $\!\bmod 2,\ $ where the first becomes $ 0 \equiv 1\pmod 2,\,$ contradiction.

Comment: Or, said more simply: $ $ even $10$ cannot divide odd $\,2x+2y-1\ \ $

Answer (score 1):

The first congruence $2x+2y=1\pmod{10}$ doesn't have any solution. If $(a,b)$ is a solution, $1=10k-2a-2b$.  RHS is even, LHS is odd.